# Unable to select date and time simultaneously in UIDatePicker ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, uidatepicker

I prepared one datepicker as follows

```
dateView =[[UIView alloc]init];
dateView.frame=CGRectMake(0, 100, appDelegate.wVal, 400);
[contentView addSubview:dateView];
datePicker =[[UIDatePicker alloc]init];
datePicker.frame = CGRectMake(0, 100, appDelegate.wVal, 300);
[datePicker setDatePickerMode:UIDatePickerModeDate];
//[datePicker addTarget:self action:@selector(fillDate:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
doneBtn =[[UIButton alloc]init];
doneBtn.frame= CGRectMake(0, datePicker.frame.origin.y+datePicker.frame.size.height+20, appDelegate.wVal, 50);
[doneBtn setTitle:@"Done" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[doneBtn  setTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
[doneBtn setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
[doneBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(doneAction) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[dateView addSubview:datePicker];
[dateView addSubview:doneBtn];
```

My doneAction method is not working.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This is the default behaviour that comes with `UIControlEventValueChanged` control event. Action handler would be triggered for any change in the control under monitor.

I would advise you to put a `Done` button in your UI. Once `Done` button is pressed, fetch data from both your date and time components and use them.

**EDIT:** Post OP' change in problem statement:

**First,** try once by setting `[dateView setUserInteractionEnabled:NO]`. This will ensure that user touches reaches subviews.

**Second,** this is not the suggested way of creating `UIButton`. You do it like this:

```
UIButton *doneButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[doneButton addTarget:self action:@selector(doneAction) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Comment: Added one button in a view but the action is not called.
     [doneBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(doneAction) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

doneAction method is not called.

Comment: Can you show the signature of your `doneAction` method.

Comment: -(void)doneAction
{
    NSLog(@"Calling done action!");
}

This method not even getting called. from that view

Comment: I believe you added your action handler in the same class whose object you are setting as target `addTarget:self `?

Comment: Looks good but can't say anything unless I see your code to add that bar and Done button in UI. Do you mind updating your question with necessary details. This is now a different issue than you asked in your question.

Answer (score 0):

hello hope this may help you to solve your problem...

Follow below steps:-

```
1)First make one view
2)In that view add uidatepicker
3)Then in that view add two buttons like done or cancel
4)Please referred  following picture [![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

Note:- I have add UIPicker.

[image]

On done button action:-

```
- (IBAction)onDatePickerDoneClick:(id)sender
{
    [self removeSubViewWithPopUpAnimation:self.datePickerView];
    self.selectedDate = [self.datePickerExpense1 date];
    self.strDateValue = [self convertDateToString:self.selectedDate dateformat:[self LocalDateFormat:@"dd MMMM yyyy"]];

    [self.tblDetails deselectRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:1 inSection:0] animated:YES];
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tblDetails cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:1 inSection:0]];
    [((UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:222])  setText:self.strDateValue];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Did you try using this?

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss"];

Comment: What does this have to do with the question?

Comment: In case of getting issue due to format,If developer has used "[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-YYYY];",Time will not be displayed.

Comment: Read the question again. It has nothing at all to do with a date formatter.